# how to print spaces of html screen?

Tags: django, html, angularjs, templates

I have in my HTML template the forwarding expression:

```
<p> {[{ message.body}]} </p>
```

The {[{ }]} is a symbol of angularjs parameter.
The parameter message.body is a string that includes several spaces but the template doesn't display the spaces at the beginning and only one space when there are several of them between words. 
How can I display the original message without eliminate spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`<pre>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp).

```
<pre> {[{ message.body }]} </pre>
```

and use CSS to customize how it looks.